# How to wrap text entries in a Vaadin Tree?

Tags: java, vaadin

I have a `Tree` with String entries. I'm looking to make the tree entry texts wrap when too long for the current layout.

The `Tree` is in a `VerticalLayout`.

The entire hierarchy of components is as follows:

```
VerticalSplitPanel > VerticalLayout > HorizontalSplitPanel > VerticalLayout > Tree
```

where `VerticalSplitPanel` at the top is the root content on the `UI`.

i tried https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/19740 without success.

how can this be done?